# Hide/show checkboxes by class according to dropdown selectedIndex

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown list with a few options and a group of checkboxes that should be available only if the user selects some particular options while filling the form.

Then, there's a group of checkboxes (4 checkboxes), 3 of which have class="extrasB" and that should be available for selection **only** if user has chosen the last 2 options in the select (5,6).

Each selected checkbox of the above adds an extra cost (it's value) to the total cost of the form (field scost). Let's say that the user selects option 5, selects some checkboxes and then decides he want's option 3 (no checkboxes). This should automatically un-select the already checked checkboxes and change the value of scost. **How do I do this?**

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HbpRn/12/) with all of the above in working order.

Comment: Sorry, I went back and edited the question a couple times and deleted the actual question! I've updated it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#symb").change(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").attr('checked', false);
    $(this).getTotal();
})
```

Change your function like this

Edit: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Kgs2/1/)

Comment: Thank you, it was $("input:checkbox").attr('checked', false);

Answer (score 0):

To know how if a checkbox is  checked:

```
if($('input[name=foo]').is(':checked'))
```

or

```
if($('input[name=foo]').attr('checked'))
```

to uncheck a checkbox:

```
$('input[name=foo]').attr('checked', false);
```

to check a checkbox:

```
$('input[name=foo]').attr('checked', true);
```

to get reference of a checkbox by class (e.g. extrasB) you do something like this:

```
$("input[type='checkbox'].extrasB").each(function(){
//check or uncheck 
});
```

Cheers!